# How to Generate monero wallet on server-side(node.js) or locally?

Tags: nodes, light-wallet, javascript

Already looking around for a few days, but can't find solution.
Found this awesome repo: https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator/blob/master/monero-wallet-generator.html.

But it's not suitable for me, I can't separate JS functions from HTML, I need only JS code to generate monero wallets.

Just maybe same functions as above but only using JS?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, solved generating monero wallets problem like that (using Meteor.js):

Downloaded this AWESOME repo: https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-core-js

Unpacked this repo to the node_modules folder.

On client startup entered this code:

```
const walletUtils = require('mymonero-core-js/monero_utils/monero_wallet_utils')
const wallet = walletUtils.NewlyCreatedWallet('english', 0)
console.log('## Wallet address:', wallet.keys.public_addr)
console.log('## Mnemonic seed:', wallet.mnemonicString)
```

So I connected mymonero-core-js lib, and used their function " NewlyCreatedWallet " to create new wallet + mnemonic phrase ( second parametr is network, where 0 is mainNet, 1 is testNet and 2 is STAGENET ).

Everything is working, now I can generate monero wallets !